# How are credit unions initially financed

Tags: united-states, credit-unions

Given that credit unions are owned by the members (and not investors) and how do they get the initial funding they need to start.

I would think they wouldn't have members until after they are formed and to form there are costs such as building and initial salaries. I would think this would be a non-trivial amount of money.

Are my assumptions right or do I have some misunderstanding about how credit unions work? 
If so where do they get the initial startup capital?

I would prefer non speculative answers about how real credit unions are funded.

Comment: If this is based in the US, http://www.ncua.gov/Resources/CUs/Dev/Pages/Start.aspx may answer your question from the US government.

Comment: Yes, i am asking about US credit unions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[​Estimated Start-Up and Operating Costs in Chartering a Credit Union](https://www.ncua.gov/Resources/Documents/CUDev/AcrobatDocument6-26-09.pdf) notes in part:

> Given the significant costs involved, most groups seek grant money and
>   non-member deposits (if pre-approved for the low-income designation)
>   to help subsidize the pre-chartering costs and annual operating
>   expenses.

Thus, in forming the union there would be the money from members and possible grants to ensure completion of the chartering process which is how one starts a CU in the US.